# Como generar una cuadricula visual en c#

Tags: c#

Necesito generar una imagen de un tablero de 50x50 con sub cuadrados de 1x1 en c#, de tal manera que pueda colorearlos como un tablero de ajedrez

Comment: Excelente ejercicio. Tú puedes!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que has realizado.